# How do I learn the type and length of a return parameter before doing the first fetch in a prepared statement with MySQL's C API?

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-5.7

I've browsed the MySQL APIs and the web in general for days, but sadly I couldn't find a clear solution to this problem, which is the last thing I need to deal with to complete the database part of my C application.

I'm using prepared statements, and I need my code to dinamically create the output `MYSQL_BIND` structures after calling `mysql_stmt_execute()` and before doing the first `mysql_stmt_fetch()`. The `MYSQL_BIND` struct needs it's `buffer` to be allocated in order to store data with the fetch, so I need to know the type of data and it's length (in case it's a string or blob) before calling fetch. The APIs [somehow offer a confusing solution for the length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-fetch.html), but there's nothing said about the type. And about the length, I don't really understand how I should access the `max_length` parameter which `mysql_stmt_store_result()` should set for each field if I follow the first strategy suggested in the aforementioned API page.

Hope someone knows this.

Comment: Is [`mysql_stmt_result_metadata()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-result-metadata.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: I knew about that, but I really can't understand how I should use them in order to get the type and length of each return column... are there designated methods for that?

Comment: How about `mysql_fetch_field()` and `mysql_fetch_fields()`? See the description of the `MYSQL_FIELD` structure [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-data-structures.html)

Comment: `mysql_fetch_field()` is an alternative to `mysql_stmt_fetch()`. It would fetch the field directly while I need to store it in the binds, and I also don't know if it's fine to use it with prepared statements... In case it works with them I could use it but I would have to re-design my software (not that I have problems in doing that if it's the only way or if it's a better solution), so I wondered if I could make this by using fetch and the output binds.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_field()` fetches the field metadata, not the data.

Comment: What bothers me is this:
`Call this function repeatedly to retrieve information about all columns in the result set. ` Will it conflict with `mysql_stmt_fetch()` or will they keep seperate pointers to the active row?  
And most of all, how do I get the result set to use it on?

Comment: I think they're independent. `mysql_fetch_field` is looping over the columns, fetching the rows has no effect on it. You can also use `mysql_fetch_fields`, which returns all the metadata about all the fields in an array.

Comment: And `mysql_fetch_field_direct()` lets you ask about a specific field, instead of looping.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_field_direct()` seems great, now I have a clear picture of how to do everything! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Barmar's comments, in case someone has my same doubts here's how I did it:

- Just after `mysql_stmt_execute()`, use `mysql_stmt_attr_set()` with `STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH` as second parameter. This will tell `mysql_stmt_store_result()` to set `max_length` for you.
- Get a `MYSQL_RES*` pointer with `mysql_stmt_store_result()` (remember to use `mysql_free_result()` when you're done with it).
- Allocate a number of binds as returned by `mysql_stmt_field_count()`
- For each output bind, get it's `MYSQL_FIELD*` pointer with `mysql_fetch_field_direct()`
- Get the column's data type from the `type` field of the `MYSQL_FIELD` struct
- Get the column's length (in case of strings and blobs) from the `max_length` field of the `MYSQL_FIELD` struct.

Now you can bind the buffers to the statement and use `mysql_stmt_fetch()` to fetch the rows in the bind.